Experience editor issue in Sitecore Headless
We are trying to set up a Sitecore headless SXA application on local with NextJS. We are facing one issue in the experience editor.
When we open a page for the first time, it loads with all placeholders and components. But when we refresh that tab, it goes blank.
Anyone faced this issue before?
Error
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. 
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error



can you please share more details about the issue? did you check the developer console on the browser to see what's going on?

Did you check logs, browser console, any error you found. Add more details.

Tried same in firefox and getting error in above image on first load of exp editor itself.

Could you incorporate an error message into the question shown in the image?

Hydration in React happens when the pre-rendered HTML from the server is turned into a fully interactive app by adding event handlers.
A common reason for issues during this process is incorrect HTML tag nesting.
For example, you might get an error if you wrap RichText in a <p> tag instead of a <div>.
Here's an incorrect way that causes an error:
<p className="page-desc text-white mb-0">
   <RichText field={props.fields.Description} />
</p>

To fix it, try either remove the <p> tag or wrap RichText in a <div> like this:
<RichText className="page-desc text-white mb-0" field={props.fields.Description} />

Refer to this for more details.
Hope this helps.
